# How to access values from JSON response which is in [object Object], [object Object] in Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, angular6

I have a JSON response , Below is my response.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "2": [
                {
                    "name": "Test1",
                    "Address": "Test2"
                },

            ]
        },
         {
            "5": [
                {
                    "name": "Test3",
                    "Address": "Test4"
                },

            ]
        },


    ]
}
```

I am able to access till data from the response.**Here "2" and "5" are date.If one date is present in this json response then for that response i have to get name and address**
But I have to show list of data.

```
<div *ngFor = "let data of result">
<span>{{data.name}}</span>
<span>{{data.Address}}</span>
</div>
```

In ts file,

```
 let result = response.data;
```

I want to access name and address from this.Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.key`, `map` and `concat` function to flat your data like this

```
let obj = this.result;
this.result = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {   
  let objkey = obj[key];
  let first = Object.keys(objkey)[0]
  return obj[key][first];
});

this.result = [].concat.apply([], this.result);
```

Demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flat-array-property

Updated:

I update demo with filter to apply your filter by date.

```
    let obj = this.result;
    var filter = '5';
    this.result = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
      let objkey = obj[key];
      let first = Object.keys(objkey)[0]
      if(filter == first){
         return obj[key][first];
      }else{
        return null;
      }

    });

    this.result = [].concat.apply([], this.result.filter(c=>c != null));
```

Comment: My requirement is like if date is 2nd, then only 2nd date data should display in list. If date is 5th, then 5th date data should display in list.basically i need to filter this based on date.Can you help me how to do this. @Hien Nguyen

Comment: Yes this is working . This is what exactly i was looking for. Thanks a lot :) . Really this saved my day. @Hien Nguyen